# Why does running Python import fails on first run but works on subsequent ones (noisereduce package)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, dependencies

Working with VS Code and Jupyter notebook extension (among others), in a virtual environment that is properly activated.
I am trying to run the following import:

```
import noisereduce
```

The **first** time I run the code, this error is shown:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2444\169068538.py in <module>
----> 1 import noisereduce

c:\Users\Username\miniconda3\envs\adsml\lib\site-packages\noisereduce\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from noisereduce.noisereduce import reduce_noise

c:\Users\Username\miniconda3\envs\adsml\lib\site-packages\noisereduce\noisereduce.py in <module>
----> 1 from noisereduce.spectralgate.stationary import SpectralGateStationary
      2 from noisereduce.spectralgate.nonstationary import SpectralGateNonStationary
      3 
      4 try:
      5     import torch

c:\Users\Username\miniconda3\envs\adsml\lib\site-packages\noisereduce\spectralgate\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from .nonstationary import SpectralGateNonStationary
      2 from .stationary import SpectralGateStationary
----> 3 from .streamed_torch_gate import StreamedTorchGate

c:\Users\Username\miniconda3\envs\adsml\lib\site-packages\noisereduce\spectralgate\streamed_torch_gate.py in <module>
----> 1 import torch
      2 from noisereduce.spectralgate.base import SpectralGate
      3 from noisereduce.torchgate import TorchGate as TG
      4 import numpy as np
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

But then, running it again works, until I restart the kernel, or reload window, or close/reopen VS Code.
Why is that? Should I try to manually install `torch` on this venv?

**Edit**
This [ugly hack] works:

```
try:
    import noisereduce
except:
    import noisereduce  # must run twice
```

**Edit 2**
Versions

```
python      3.9.16
noisereduce 3.0.0
VSCode      1.84.2
```

Comment: what happens if you install `torch` in that venv

Comment: @rioV8 I tried but aborted the installation because it was taking ages and the dry run shown some dependencies issues. As this is a venv of an online course I am taking I am avoiding touching it too much. To be 100% transparent there is a yml for the environment and `noisereduce` was under `pip` section and I removed it on course section 1 because it was causing issues. But now I need it for the very last section of the course :/ I tried to install libmamba solver to speed up installation so I may try again, will update the question.

Comment: please add version info to your question post of the relevant software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that is some issue of the 3.0.0 version.
From the noisereduce github:
https://github.com/timsainb/noisereduce/issues/96

The owner suggets to use the patch-torch-dependency branch.

Comment: For other people with same issue, use either the hack or this command to install `v3.0.1` while waiting for the patch to be in master: `pip install git+git://github.com/timsainb/noisereduce@patch-torch-dependency`